# Design Pattern in Lippman's C++ Primer

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface

I am fairly new to programming so bear with my question if the answer is obvious.

In section 15.9 of C++ Primer, 5th ed., by Lippman, Lajoie, and Moo, the section involves programming an inheritance hierarchy.  It's basically an abstract class, `Query_base`, whose children are `WordQuery`, `NotQuery`, and `BinaryQuery`, the last of which branches further into `AndQuery` and `OrQuery`.  The `Query_base` hierarchy is accessed via pointer by an interface class called `Query`.  The basic idea behind this setup is to use compound queries such as this:

`Query q = Query("fiery") & Query("bird") | Query("wind")`

(These operators generate `Query` objects that point to `Query_base`-type objects, e.g., the '`&`' generates an `AndQuery`, the '`~`' generates a `NotQuery`.

Text documents can then be searched for lines that meet the rules of the query.)

The class Query_base is as follows:

```
class Query_base {
    friend class Query;
protected:
    virtual ~Query_base() = default;
private:
    virtual QueryResult eval(const TextQuery&) const = 0;
    virtual std::string rep() const = 0;
}
```

All Query_base children implement eval() and rep() and so are instantiable.

The class Query is designed as follows:

```
class Query {
    friend Query operator~(const Query&);
    friend Query operator|(const Query&, const Query&);
    friend Query operator&(const Query&, const Query&);
public:
    Query(const std::string&);
    QueryResult eval(const TextQuery &t) const { return q->eval(t); }
    std::string rep() const { return q->rep(); }
private:
    Query(std::shared_ptr<Query_base> query) : q(query) { }
    std::shared_ptr<Query_base> q;
```

So my understanding is that the design has an inheritance hierarchy and then an interface that are deliberately separate from one another.  The latter accesses the former from the side, as it were, rather than just have the base class serve as the interface.

I have two questions:

1. Is there anything wrong with not having a separate `Query` class?  Can we just have the `Query_base` class serve as both the base for the hierarchy and the interface, and get rid of the `Query` class?  I recognize that as `Query_base` stands, it cannot, because it has pure virtual functions, but these could be changed.  E.g., couldn't I just move over the `Query` function implementations for `eval()` and `rep()` into `Query_base`?  Is there anything wrong with doing that?  Does the `shared_ptr<Query_base>` in `Query` complicate things and is the basis for the separation, and if so, can we work around that problem?
2. How common is it for there to be a hierarchy-interface separation like this (if that is the right way to think of this)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No inheritance, Query_base is not the base class of Query.   In spite of the (poor) name, there is no relationship at all between these classes.  Otherwise the reason that the `friend` keyword was necessary.  Look up "encapsulation" in the book.

Comment: To be clear: I understand that `Query` is not at all part of the `Query_base` inheritance hierarchy.  That is why, as you say, `friend Query` is necessary in the `Query_base` class.  In fact, this separation between `Query` and `Query_base` is PRECISELY what my question is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The need of the separation becomes clear if we continue to implement all these operators and other subquery types. Let's imagine, e.g., how & operator could look like.

`&` operator should construct a query, which, in turn,  should contain two other queries.
So, `AndQuery` class could be defined like this:

```
class AndQuery: public BinaryQuery {
public:
     AndQuery(const Query_base& lhs, const Query_base& rhs);
     AndQuery(Query_base&& lhs, Query_base&& rhs);
     ...
     QueryResult eval(const TextQuery& t) override;
private:
     // required members and private methods...
     // two principal members, lhsQuery and rhsQuery for
     // left hand side subquery and light hand side subquery
     // correspondingly are defined in `BinaryQuery`
};
```

and, in a simple *unoptimized* case, `AndQuery` should perform searches (`eval()`) somehow like this:

```
QueryResult AndQuery::eval(const TextQuery& t) {
    QueryResult lhsResult = lhsQuery.eval(t);
    QueryResult rhsResult = rhsQeury.eval(t);
    // the resulting ResultSet should include only entries
    // from both result sets
    for(auto it = lhsResult.begin(); it != lhsResult.end(); ++it)
        if (rhsResult.find(*it) == rhsResult::cend())
            it = lhsResult.erase(it);
    // now we can return lhsResult because we have erased all elements from it 
    // which weren't in rhsResult
    return lhsResult;
}
```

Other query components subclasses have their own specific implementations. In turn, `Query` has its own set of specific methods, like constructing query from a string. Without a pure virtual `Query_base` we had to share the implementation details of `Query` with all component subclasses. Also we had to make those classes be visible to external users.

By using a separate "interface" `Query` class we provide a clear understandable *lean* interface to users of the subsystem.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  As for my second question, is it common to use a side interface class that gives users of a subsystem access to a class hierarchy?

Comment: Well, for cases when there's a big 'backyard' machinery not to be exposed to the outer world, it's quite common to use a cover class, or, maybe, a cover function, if it's possible. Certainly this could prolongate the design stage of the project,  'cause you need to plan your class hierarchy more carefully. However,  it has obvious benefits. E.g. it decreases possible uses of your classes to only 'valid', intended cases, this simplifying further modifications of your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

aside from comments above, I think this design also has to do with polymorphism in c++, which is only supported through reference and pointer, but not the object itself.

By using a "Query" object that has no hierarchy and an embedded smart pointer to Query_Base that has hierarchy and polymorphism, the users of the class can use Query object to achieve a polymorphism effect.